# Blocking Serial Port Read

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, serial-port

I have to read many(8) serial devices on my project. They are Pantilt, Camera, GPS, Compass etc. they all are RS232 devices but they have different command structure and behavior. e.g GPS starts sending data as 
soon as I open the port. where as PanTilt and Camera only responds when I send specific commands to them.

I use following environment

- OS: Ubuntu 11.10
- Language: C++
- Framework: Qt 4.7

For PanTilt and Camera I want to develop function like this.

```
int SendCommand(string& command, string& response)
{ 
    port.write(command, strlen(command));
    while(1)
    {
       if(response contains '\n') break;
       port.read(response) // Blocking Read
    } 
    return num_of_bytes_read;
}
```

I want to implement this way as this function will be used as building block for more complex algorithm
like this...

```
SendCoammd("GET PAN ANGLE", &angle);
  if(angle > 60)
     SendCommand("STOP PAN", &stopped?);
     if(stopped? == true)
        SendCommand("REVERSE PAN DIRECTION", &revesed?);
        if(reversed? == true)
           SendCommand("START PAN", &ok);
```

To do something like this I need strict synchronous behavior. Anybody has any idea how to approach this?

Comment: (unrelated nitpicker note: passing `string &` is not a good idea, probably you want `const string &` or just `string`; also, `strlen` on a `string` makes no sense, you should use its `size` method)

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial very intresting and helpful.
http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

It shows how boost::asio can be used to perform both sync and async read/write.

Thank You for the help!

Comment: This should rather be a comment to your question (or you could edit the question) rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem of using standard file API?

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyX");
write(fd, command.cstr(), command.size());
vector v(MAX_SIZE);
read(fd,&v[0], MAX_SIZE);
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I already tried QextSerialPort on qt but used the SerilalPort in ::EventDriven mode. so I have to implement readyRead() signal. This is asynchronous read. But for my application I think synchronous write/read should be useful. Somehow QextSerialPort does not work with ::Polling mode.

Answer (score 0):

Low-level communication with serial port in Qt can be established with [`QExtSerialPort`](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) library that partially implements [`QIODevice`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html) interface.

The high level protocols you have to implement yourself.

Comment: I tried QextSerialPort it works in ::EventDriven mode but not in ::Polling. I think I need to create the SerialPort in ::Polling mode as I need synchronous Write/Read. Is that correct? Somehow Polling is not working. I will post the code shortly. Thank You!

Comment: @user1366507, may be some cases do not work (I use relatively old version of this library and it does not support even events), but you can always move from events to blocking mode using additional thread.